# TortoiseGit Comment on Each File with Only One Commit

Tags: commit, tortoisegit

Sincerely hope this isn't absolutely obvious, but in TortoiseGit, I can create a comment on an entire commit. To get per file commit comments I end up just doing  a git commit many times creating a comment and selecting which files. Then I do a push. While this works it creates a ton of commits (12 files 12 commits for example). How do I do one commit with different comments on different files? Or this not possible and I'm looking at this wrong?

I didn't see information on this here: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-commit.html

Comment: Not possible! (Usually, one commit, one thing. If the changes of each single file is not for the same purpose, then you should commit one file each time.)

Comment: Makes sense, tanks for resolving that and providing a good practice.

Comment: If you really want to comment on each file, I just figure out one way(it's nothing to do with git or TortoiseGit): You can host your repository on GitHub/GitLab, then you can comment on every single file/line you modified. But those comment data are saved on GitHub/GitLab, not on repository itself.

Comment: That's really helpful, and a number of my repos are on GitHub, so I'll check that out. Thanks.